# Three.js - Generating new faceVertexUvs when subdividing a geometry

Tags: three.js

## Summary

I'm currently researching different types of subdivision algorithms.

When I subdivide a geometry, UVs are not generated properly, resulting in faces with no material, i.e holes in my mesh.

Here is a [link](https://larryzodiac.github.io/Generative-Jewellery/build/02/02.2/index.html) to my exercise.

(I need more reputation to post images..)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/larryzodiac/Generative-Jewellery/master/images/shape.png

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/larryzodiac/Generative-Jewellery/master/images/shape-gaps.png

Three.js uses [Loop subdivision](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/subdivision.html). I have been coding based on a Three.js example found [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js).

As part of my research I have coded a working(nearly) example of [Catmull-Clark](http://graphics.cs.ucdavis.edu/~joy/GeometricModelingLectures/Unit-9/Unit9.html) subdivision

## Problem

Using Catmull-Clark on a face results in three new faces(*quads*) in place of the source face.

As THREE.Face4 is deprecated, I have opted to simply create two triangles(Face3) in place of each quad. I know this is odd and not optimal but try to ignore it.

Therefore, there will be six new faces created in place of a source face.

**Some of the faces have UVs. I can't figure out where I am going wrong in mapping UVs to all newly created faces.**

## Code Extracts

[Here](https://github.com/larryzodiac/Generative-Jewellery/tree/master/build/02/02.2) is a link to the exercise code on Github.

Catmull-Clark.js:

```
  ...

  /*
  Step 4
  Redraw geometry
  */

  // Throwing together all new/old vertices for the new geometry
  const newVertices = vertexPoints.concat(edgePoints,facePoints);
  const newFaces = [];
  const newUVs = [];

  let uv, x0, x1, x2; // Source triangle face points
  let xe0 = new THREE.Vector2(); // Edge points (mid-points)
  let xe1 = new THREE.Vector2();
  let xe2 = new THREE.Vector2();
  let xf = new THREE.Vector2(); // Face point of face (centre-ish)

  // Loop through each face, create sudivided faces from found algorithm points
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceFaces.length; i++) {
    const face = sourceFaces[i];

    const edgePoint1 = getEdgePoint(face.a, face.b, sourceEdges, edgePoints) + sourceVertices.length;
    const edgePoint2 = getEdgePoint(face.b, face.c, sourceEdges, edgePoints) + sourceVertices.length;
    const edgePoint3 = getEdgePoint(face.c, face.a, sourceEdges, edgePoints) + sourceVertices.length;

    const facePoint = getFacePoint(face.a, face.b, face.c, sourceEdges, facePoints) + sourceVertices.length + edgePoints.length;

    /*
    Catmull for ARBITRARY shapes, all faces after the first iteration become quads.
    THREE.Face4 has been depreciated in the new Three.js build
    Solution will be to draw a quad using two triangles.
    */

    createNewFace(newFaces, face.a, edgePoint1, edgePoint3, facePoint);
    createNewFace(newFaces, face.b, edgePoint2, edgePoint1, facePoint);
    createNewFace(newFaces, face.c, edgePoint3, edgePoint2, facePoint);

    // create 4 new uv's
    uv = sourceUvs[i];
    x0 = uv[0];
    x1 = uv[1];
    x2 = uv[2];


    // xe0.set(midpoint(x0.x, x1.x), midpoint(x0.y, x1.y));
    // xe1.set(midpoint(x1.x, x2.x), midpoint(x1.y, x2.y));
    // xe2.set(midpoint(x0.x, x2.x), midpoint(x0.y, x2.y));
    // xf.set( ((x0.x + x1.x + x2.x)/3) , ((x0.y + x1.y + x2.y)/3) );

    xe0.set(newVertices[edgePoint1].x, newVertices[edgePoint1].y);
    xe1.set(newVertices[edgePoint2].x, newVertices[edgePoint2].y);
    xe2.set(newVertices[edgePoint3].x, newVertices[edgePoint3].y);
    xf.set(newVertices[facePoint].x, newVertices[facePoint].y);

    createNewUv(newUVs, x0, xe0, xf);
    createNewUv(newUVs, x0, xe2, xf);
    createNewUv(newUVs, x1, xe0, xf);
    createNewUv(newUVs, x1, xe1, xf);
    createNewUv(newUVs, x2, xe1, xf);
    createNewUv(newUVs, x2, xe2, xf);
  }

  geometry.vertices = newVertices;
  geometry.faces = newFaces;
  geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = newUVs;
```

This is the way I have it working, forgive the bad diagram:

```
    // ------------------------------------------------- //
    //                          x0
    //                         / \
    //                       /    \
    //                     /       \
    //                   /          \
    //               xe0  \        / xe2      // Creates three quads
    //               /      \ xf /    \
    //             /          |        \
    //           /           |          \
    //         /            |            \
    //      x1 - - - - - - xe1 - - - - - - x2
    // ------------------------------------------------- //

    // ------------------------------------------------- //
    //                          x0
    //                         / \
    //                       /  | \
    //                     /   |   \
    //                   /     |    \
    //               xe0  \   |    / xe2      // Need to divide quads into  two triangles
    //               /      \ xf /    \
    //             /       /  |  \     \
    //           /      /    |      \   \
    //         /    /       |         \  \
    //      x1 - - - - - - xe1 - - - - - - x2
    // ------------------------------------------------- //
```

structure-query-functions.js :

```
// THREE.Face4 depreciated
// Need to draw two triangles to emulate quad

const createNewFace = (newFaces, a, b, c, d, materialIndex) => {
  newFaces.push(new THREE.Face3(
    a, b, d, undefined, undefined, materialIndex
  ));
  newFaces.push(new THREE.Face3(
    a, c, d, undefined, undefined, materialIndex
  ));
}
```

```
const createNewUv = (newUvs, a, b, c) => {
  newUvs.push( [ a.clone(), b.clone(), c.clone() ] );
}
```

```
const midpoint = (a, b) => (Math.abs(b - a) / 2) + Math.min(a, b);
```

Have I missed or overlooked anything? I have been studying different questions on Stack and the Three website but to no avail. Regardless, cheers for taking the time to read, offer feedback, and help.

I hope I am making sense.

Sound, Papa bless.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're adding three values each time you invoke `createNewUv`. Shouldn't the `newUvs` array include only two values per UV?

Comment: The geometry property of 'faces' holds an array of objects where each object holds three vertices that define a face. The 'faceVertexUvs' array holds arrays that store a uv for each point on that corresponding face. Or at least that's my understanding, might be wrong. See the console of my exercise, I've logged the geometry.

Answer (score 2):

In your demo I can see missing faces from the other side.
Seems you encountered [backface culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling).

When adding new face check if it is oriented as intended. In your example you have all required info to order vertices properly.

In more general case you can check `dotProduct(crossProduct(B-A, C-A), supposedFaceNormal) > 0`. If face is not oriented properly just flip it by rearranging vertices (ABC -> ACB).

To make both triangle sides drawn set [material.side](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.side) property to `THREE.DoubleSide`.

Can't see uv generation problems with single red color. If there is one - please demonstrate it in example with uvs drawn somehow.

Comment: Also representing {a, b, c, d} quad as triangles {a, b, d} and {a, c, d} doesn't sound right. If `ad` is diagonal - ordering is wrong.

Comment: @mikn In the general case, you are right. There is no way around checking and picking one of the 2 candidate triangles. Unless, there is a known order of the vertices to begin with. As in knowing  beforehand if they follow a clockwise or counter clockwise order.

Comment: Cheers lads, I'll have a gawk and see what I can do. Appreciate it.